# Windows Admin center and upload files with no progression

Tags: server, window, admin, center, wac

I have a dedicated server with hyper-v core 2019.
I installed Windows Admin Center on my windows 10 client.
It works fine except the transfer file function. i can read remote disks and create folder but when i try to upload file, the bar progress stay at 0% and nothing happens.

I have create a rule on firewall who accepts all traffic for my ip adress.

Someone could help me please?
thanks for advance
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with Windows Admin center. (assuming you are trying to upload a file of more than 100Mb)

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/support/known-issues#files

Still very much a work in progress...

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a specific port to make this work.

You can verify this by temporarily disabling the firewall with this powershell command:

```
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled False   // Disable firewall
Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled True    // Re-enable
```

I had once found this port (don't even ask how...), nagged to the people writing the documentation for MS, they pointed me to a corner on the internet that the port was mentioned, but now I still can't find it! This is outrageous...!

**Update:**

OK, I found it again! It is port 445!

And here is the documentation link: [Port configuration on the target server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/deploy/prepare-environment#port-configuration-on-the-target-server)

Turns out you need to know the port in advance to find it! (lol)

Here is a script to do this:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "__Allow_File_UploadDownload" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 445 -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -RemoteAddress 192.168.1.5

(Note: Replace "192.168.1.5" with a whitelisted IP)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!  The firewall rule wasn't necessary after following the steps under Prepare Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2016 in that same link you provided.  Everything started working.

Comment: The rule isn't necessary because step 3, which has you enable File and iSCSI Services and File Server, automatically creates the rule.